Displaying a checkbox in Vue Quasar Tree
How can I remove the checkbox display for parent nodes, i.e. nodes that have children in the component Tree.
I tried it through the class.
.q-checkbox__inner) {
  display: none;

But then all the checkboxes disappear. I would like to know how to do this

Use a more specific CSS selector that target only the one you want.

This is achievable out of the box just using the QTree API.  Please refer to the documentation.
Given a node with children, give the node noTick: true property to remove it's checkbox.
{
  label: 'Test', noTick: true,
  children: [
    { label: 'Foo'},
    { label: 'Bar'},
    { label: 'Baz'}
  ]
}

